# Missing Keyword (ORA-00905) - Oracle SQL Case Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

hello can anyone help me i get these error when using case statement

```
(select distinct case 

     when mtt.transaction_type_name   = 'Miscellaneous Receipt'  then pha.segment1 is  null
     when mtt.transaction_type_name  = 'Return from Maintenance' then pha.segment1 is  null
     else mtt.transaction_type_name
      END AS trans
     from  mtl_material_transactions mmt                             
     where 1=1 
     AND msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
     AND ph.po_header_id = pha.po_header_id

    )
```

Comment: `then pha.segment1 is  null`??? WHat should that do?

Comment: if you need  a null result use `then null `

Comment: Why the useless parentheses around the statement?

Comment: pha.segment1 is the po number